# Retrieve tweets based on twitter list name

Tags: twitter, twitterizer

Is it possible to get all/latest tweets from twitter public list?

Example list: https://twitter.com/#!/thecaucus/u-s-senate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use: `TwitterList.GetStatuses(...)`

There should be an overload that doesn't require tokens, but it appears to be missing. You should be able to pass null/Nothing into the tokens if it's a public list to fetch it anonymously.

Comment: Hi we have used the following api request to get latest tweets http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=LACity_org&include_entities=true&result_type=recent is there any way we can modify the same url to get tweets from public list